# Getting information from a file without traversing its contents

Tags: c++, file, file-io, filestream

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132151/how-to-find-number-of-characters-in-a-file-without-traversing-the-contents) made me search for what else can I get from a file without traversing its contents (means without inputting the contents using ifstream or getc etc).

Other than file size and number of characters, what other information can I gather? I searched [`fseek`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/), I found I can use `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR` and `SEEK_END`, which only allow me to find the end of the file, start of the file and current pointer.

In order to make it a question, I specifically want to ask:

1. Can occurrences of some character or type of character (newline etc) be counted?
2. Can its contents be matched with a certain template?
3. Is using these methods faster than reading the file multiple times?

And I am asking about Microsoft Windows, not Linux.

Comment: templated data is why you have .doc, .xml, .ps, ... etc

Comment: If you know what information you want up front and the file is not changing, you *never* have to read a file multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **No**, becuase searching of something in unpredicteble conditions requires thorough examing of contents. Examing is reading. Of course, you may collect some statistics before, but you need to traverse you data not less then once. You can use other applications to do this implicitly, but they also will traverse your file from very begining to the end. You may orginize your file some way to obtain necessary info with minimal amount of read-operations, but its all up to your task, and there is no general approach (Because any generiosuty comes to examing the whole source structure).

2) Also **No** (see above)

3) **Yes**. Store as much as possible (or required by task) in memory (that's called *caching*). For example, use mapping (See [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows and mmap(2) on *nix systems), this uses some in-system caching mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

1. No
2. No
3. Depends on wether there's an actual need to read the file multiple times.

There're no miracles here. The former question had a "shortcut" because the number of characters in the file equals to its size in bytes (more strictly speaking - the ansi-text file is considered of a character sequence, each is represented by a single byte).

Answer (score 2):

The [`stat` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) contains information about the file, including permissions, ownership, size, access and creation date info. As for metadata, maybe there's an API to tie into a Windows search database that might allow searching on other criteria, like content attributes (I'm a Linux guy, usually, so I don't know what Windows offers in this respect).